# Uncaught TypeError: ctx.clearReact is not a function at animate

Tags: javascript, html

Im pretty new here and in coding, and Im trying to finish this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d620nV6bp0A&ab_channel=Frankslaboratory

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas1');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

let particlesArray;

let mouse = {
    x: null,
    y: null,
    radius: (canvas.height/80) * (canvas.width/80)
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove',
function(event){
    mouse.x = event.x;
    mouse.y = event.y;
}
);

class Particle {
    constructor(x, y, directionX, directionY, size, color){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.directionX = directionX;
        this.directionY = directionY;
        this.size = size;
        this.color = color;
    }
    draw() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.size, 0, Math.PI * 2, false );
        ctx.fillStyle = '#8C5523';
        ctx.fill();
    }
    update() {
        if(this.x > canvas.width || this.x <0 ){
                this.directionX = - this.directionX;      
        }
        if(this.y > canvas.height || this.y < 0){
            this.directionY = - this.directionY;
        }
        let dx = mouse.x - this.x;
        let dy = mouse.y - this.y;
        let distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)
        if (disance < mouse.radius + this.size){
            if(mouse.x < this.x && this.x <canvas.width - this.size * 10){
                this.x += 10;
            }
            if(mouse.x >this.x && this.x > this.size *10){
                this.x -=10;
            }
            if(mouse.y < this.y && this.y < canvas.height - this.size * 10){
                this.y += 10;
            }
            if(mouse.y > this.y && this.y > this.size * 10){
                this.y -= 10;
            }
        }
        this.x += this.directionX;
        this.y += this.directionY;

        this.draw();
    }
}
function init() {
    particlesArray = [];
    let numberOfParticles = (canvas.height * canvas.width) / 9000;
    for (let i = 0; i < numberOfParticles *2 ; i++){
        let size = (Math.random() * 5 ) + 1;
        let x = (Math.random() * ((innerWidth - size * 2) - (size * 2)) + size * 2);
        let y = (Math.random() * ((innerHeight - size * 2) - (size * 2)) + size * 2);
        let directionX = (Math.random() * 5) - 2.5;
        let directionY = (Math.random() * 5) - 2.5;
        let color = '#8C5523';

        particlesArray.push(new Particle(x, y ,directionX, directionY, size, color));
    }
}
function connect(){
    let opacityValue = 1;
    for( let a=0; a < particlesArray.length; a++ ){
        for(let b = a; b < particlesArray.length; b++){
            let distance = (( particlesArray[a].x - particlesArray[b].x) 
            * (particlesArray[a].x - particlesArray[b].x)) 
            + ((particlesArray[a].y - particlesArray[b].y) * 
            (particlesArray[a] .y - particlesArray[b].y));
            if(distance < (canvas.width/7) * (canvas.height/7)){
               opacityValue = 1 - (distance/20000);
                ctx.strokeStyle='rgba(140,85,31,' + opacityValue + ')';
                ctx.lineWidth = 1;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(particlesArray[a].x, particlesArray[a].y);
                ctx.lineTo(particlesArray[b].x, particlesArray[b].y);
                ctx.stroke();
            }
        }
    }
}

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame (animate);
    ctx.clearReact(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)
    for (let i = 0; i < particlesArray.length; i++) {
        particlesArray[i].update();
    }
    connect();
}

window.addEventListener('resize',
function(){
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    mouse.radius = ((canvas.height/80) * (canvas.height/80));
    init();
}
);
window.addEventListener('mouseout',
function(){
    mouse.x = undefined;
    mouse.x = undefined;
}
)


init();
animate();
```

```css
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
#canvas1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: radial-gradient(#ffc38c,#ff9b40);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>MyWebsitePLAX</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I am making progress up to this point and then I have a lot of errors in my console stacking and saying: "Uncaught TypeError: ctx.clearReact is not a function
at animate"
When I open this project nothing is rendering on website. I Find out that here is some kind of problem

```
 function animate(){
        requestAnimationFrame (animate);
        ctx.clearReact(0, 0, innerWidth, innerHeight)
        for (let i = 0; i < particlesArray.length; i++) {
            particlesArray[i].update();
        }
        connect();
    }
```

Could some1 possible help to solve this problem and explain some part of it to  :)?

Comment: Typo: `ctx.clearReact()` -> `ctx.clearRect()`

Comment: Rly thanks for advice m8 :) i find out there was also one more typo everthing works now :)